# jOOQ: Find constraints in a specific table

Tags: java, jooq, flyway

While working in jOOQ-agnostic (without code generation) migrations I've encountered a situation in which I need to check if a constraint (unique, foreign key) already exists in the database in order to complete further operations.

What I've tried so far is to run the drop and try to catch the exception, but it fails the transaction and stops following migrations from happening

```
dsl.alterTable(table).dropConstraint(constraintName).execute();
...
>>  ERROR: constraint "t_client_name_unique" of relation "t_client" does not exist
```

Setup:

- Spring
- jOOQ without code generation
- FlywayDB as migrations library
- Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Future solutions (not available in jOOQ 3.12)

For jOOQ 3.13+, we're investing heavily in supporting more such migration scenarios. In the future, we'll support some vendor agnostic `information_schema` style views that produce this kind of meta information for all databases: [#8301](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8301)

Another feature that could help you here immediately would be native `DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS` support: [#9557](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9557). You could, of course, use [plain SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) to run this particular statement on PostgreSQL, until [#9557](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9557) is available

#### A solution right now

Alternatively, in your case, since you're only using PostgreSQL, you could do this directly by querying PostgreSQL's `information_schema`. You could generate `information_schema` tables and then run this query:

```sql
select *
from information_schema.table_constraints
where constraint_schema = :constraint_schema
and constraint_name = :constraint_name
```